# Heroku deploy error : Cannot find module 'Express'

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Node.js app on heroku. But whenever I try to deploy it throws error - Cannot find module "Express". Despite already being mentioned in package.json file, it is still throwing the error. I have followed every step mentioned in Heroku Node.js docs and looked up the problem everywhere and did everything needed. Here's my package.json file -

```
 {
  "name": "kimaya_soft",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application for school",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Anjali Ahlawat",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  }
}
```

Deploy log-

```
    2020-12-05T16:14:35.338290+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
2020-12-05T16:14:35.339736+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347204+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347205+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347205+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347205+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347206+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'Express'
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347206+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347208+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347208+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/startup/routes.js:1:17)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347209+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347209+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347209+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347210+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347210+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347210+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347211+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347211+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:5:1)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347211+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347212+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.347212+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2020-12-05T16:14:35.406916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-05T16:14:35.479240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-05T16:17:49.304494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kimaya-school-app.herokuapp.com request_id=3acd680f-946a-4c2a-82ef-d20c1ce1d3cc fwd="106.215.0.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-05T16:17:49.834239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kimaya-school-app.herokuapp.com request_id=2beb12ac-d1df-4398-a9f0-c8820bf05284 fwd="106.215.0.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

File structure -

```
->classes
->config
    ->default.json
->functions
->kimaya-school-app
->middleware
->modals
->node_modules
->routes
->startup
    ->db.js
    ->prod.js
    ->routes.js
->.gitignore
->index.js
->package-lock.json
->package.json
->Procfile
->sendMail.js
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have included _this_ `package.json` in the root of your repository in the code you are trying to deploy? And you have pushed to Heroku's `main` or `master` branch, not a branch with another name? When your application deploys, do you see Express being installed?

Comment: Yes, the package is included in the right directory and I have pushed main branch also. But I cannot see Express being installed though I have added it in package.json file.

Comment: Please show us your file structure and deploy logs.

Comment: I have added the deploy logs and file structure. Hope this would help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package.json looks ok to me, but the part that caught my attention is the "Express" part inside the logs. Is there any part of your code that imports express like this?

```js
var express = require('Express'),
```

If so, you should import it using only lowercase.

Comment: Yes Deliton. Thank you. I did go through all the files where I have imported express and it turned out that I imported "Express' in one of files.